# Can micronaut work with gateways like zuul or spring cloud gateway?

Tags: netflix-zuul, micronaut

The main issue is the compatibility of the registry.
If not, how to deal with gateway issues?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depends what you mean. You can use Zuul or Spring Cloud Gateway as your gateway solution in front of a Micronaut application.

Ultimately a Micronaut application will register itself with Eureka or Consul and then Zuul or SCG will discovery the service via service discovery and route requests to the Micronaut app over HTTP.